# Remove selected entry on other drop-down list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datalist

I have 2 `DropDownList`s with same contents (i.e. finance, marketing, promotion). I want to remove already-selected values from the rest of the list.

Example: If I select "finance" for the 1st list, it should be removed on other list; the 2nd list should only display "marketing" and "promotion".

However, the current code still display all values on other list when whatever value is selected on the 1st one.

**ASP.NET Page**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dldepart" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" Height="343px" Width="1572px" onitemdatabound="dldepart_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlist" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlist_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**ASP.NET C# Code**

```
private void BindCheckBoxList()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\database\personal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct depart FROM datalist", con);
        SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);

        Da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dldepart.DataSource = dt;
            dldepart.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Fetch Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void dldepart_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlist = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlist"); 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\database\personal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct depart FROM datalist", con);
        SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);

        /**codes that i used to repeat datalist **/
        Da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlist.DataSource=dt;
            ddlist.DataTextField="depart";
            ddlist.DataValueField="depart";
            ddlist.DataBind();
            ddlist.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
            ddlist.Items.FindByText("Select").Value = Convert.ToString(0); 
        }
    }
      catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

**On SelectedIndexChange**

```
protected void ddlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataListItem dlitem = (DataListItem)((DropDownList)sender).Parent;
    CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = (CheckBoxList)dlitem.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
    DropDownList ddlist = (DropDownList)dlitem.FindControl("ddlist"); 
    // DataBoundControl DataSource = (DataBind)dldepart.FindControl("DataSource");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\database\personal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,subDepatment FROM datalist where depart='" + ddlist.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);

        Da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dt;
            CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "subDepatment"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
            CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "Id"; // the id of the items displayed
            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain master collection which will hold dropdown list values and one collection which will hold selected values. Bind dropdown by applying filter as master collection - selected collection. And you need to add or delete from selected collection only if dropdown value changes.

So consider example as -

MasterList collection -finance, marketing ,promotion
Selected Collection - Empty

Now for each dropdown you apply filter Masterlist - Selected and bind.

So for all Dropdown values marketing, Finance, Promotion.
You select Marketing for first dropdown then for second dropdown values available ill be =Masterlist - Selected = Finance and Promition.

And if you are binding dropdown only by querying DB then it will be simple.

Answer (score 0):

//i tried this and it worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function funcCheck(obj)
      {
      var isSelected=false;
      var selectedVal=$(obj).val();
      var ctrlId=$(obj).attr("id");
      alert(selectedVal);
      alert($("[id*=ddlist]").length);
        $("[id*=ddlist]").each(function(){
            if($.trim($(this).attr("id"))!=$.trim(ctrlId))
            {
                if(selectedVal == $(this).val())
                {
                    isSelected=true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        if(isSelected)
        {
            alert("Value is already selected");
            $(obj).val(0);
            return false;
        }
      }
</script>
```